# Emacs: highlight matching paren when cursor is on it, not after it

Tags: emacs

Emacs highlights closing paren when the cursor is on it, and highlights the opening paren when the cursor is *after* it. That seems to be some sort of "global" behaviour - functions like C-M-b and C-M-f follow the same pattern.

That is ugly (to my taste) and ambiguous: when you read some hairy code and meet smth like  `( ... ){ ... }` with no space in between - you can't highlight the `}` by putting the cursor on `{` and have to jump with C-M-f or put a selection with C-M-space.

Is there a way to change that behaviour?

Comment: I suppose you do highlighting with `show-paren-mode`?

Comment: @pmr, yes, that is right

Comment: Similar: [Emacs: Matching parenthesis when cursor is ON closing parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25648067)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/mic-paren.el, it will highlight *both* parenthesis. For example:

```
( ... )<cursor>{ ... }
```

Here, both `(` and `}` will be highlighted.

Comment: Coulnd't find a way to make it highlight the close paren when cursor is before it (on it), but at least that removes ambiguity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Provided a toolset whose forward-commands put cursor at the last visible character of a form.

Where forward-word would stop after

```
foo bar baz 

   ^   ^
```

ar-forward-word-atpt would stop

```
foo bar baz
  ^   ^   ^
```

Same with lists.

See also ar-highlight-paren-atpt-mode

Everthing still under construction...

Maybe get the trunk via

bzr branch lp:s-x-emacs-werkstatt

https://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/