# Emacs: Matching parenthesis when cursor is ON closing parenthesis

Tags: emacs, elisp

{It has been asked before: [Emacs: highlight matching paren when cursor is on it, not after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399530/emacs-highlight-matching-paren-when-cursor-is-on-it-not-after-it) but none of the answers are satisfactory}

I am using mic-paren with following .emacs settings (although the problem exists with all similar emacs packages, so it seems to be some kind of default emacs behavior)

```
    (paren-activate)
    (setq paren-match-face 'highlight)
    (setq paren-sexp-mode t)
```

which highlight the all the text between two parenthesis. It works well when the cursor is ON opening parenthesis but from the other side, I have to put my cursor AFTER the closing parenthesis. This results in strange behavior when used with slime (which requires the cursor to be put ON the closing parenthesis to display general usage information and such). Is there any way to change this behavior and make emacs match parenthesis when the cursor is ON closing parenthesis?

EDIT: Minor grammar fix

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98850/emacs-changing-show-paren-mode-areas (there with `show-paren-mode` instead of `mic-paren`).

Comment: It also leaves the afterglow. Not that I'm bothered by it...

Comment: Related: [show-paren-mode only highlights when cursor is one character after closing parenthesis](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for `mic-paren'. But, it has some afterglow;-). The opening delimiter is highlighted if the cursor is on the closing delimiter or just behind it.

```lisp
(defadvice mic-paren-highlight (around cursorOnClosing activate)
  "Dirty hack to highlight sexps with closing delim below cursor"
  (if (eq (char-syntax (following-char)) ?\) )
      (let ((paren-priority 'close))
        (save-excursion
          (forward-char)
          ad-do-it))
    ad-do-it))
```

Naturally, to make this work you need to install `mic-paren` correctly. Just follow the installation guide in `mic-paren.el` cited here:

Installation:

- Place this file in a directory in your 'load-path and byte-compile
  it. You can surely ignore the warnings.
- Put the following in your .emacs file:
  (GNU Emacs supports mic-paren only within a window-system but XEmacs
  supports mic-paren also without X)

```lisp
   (when (or (featurep 'xemacs) window-system)
      (require 'mic-paren) ; loading
      (paren-activate)     ; activating
   ; set here any of the customizable variables of mic-paren:
   ; ...
   )
```

- Restart your Emacs. mic-paren is now installed and activated!
- To list the possible customizations enter `C-h f paren-activate' or
  go to the customization group`mic-paren-matching'.

EDITS:

- follow Stefan's hint about `(featurep 'xemacs)`

Comment: Afterglow! Made me laugh once I got what you meant by it. I've added a hook in your answer just in case someone new to emacs (yesterday-me) thinks it's not working (again-yesterday-me).

Comment: `(string-match "XEmacs\\|Lucid" emacs-version)` should be written `(featurep 'xemacs)` which is not only shorter but also significantly more efficient (the byte-compiler optimizes it away completely).

Comment: @Stefan Adopted your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about mic-paren, but using the built-in `show-paren-mode`, you can get what you want in Emacs-24.4 with:

```
(defun my-show-paren-any (orig-fun)
  (or (funcall orig-fun)
      (if (looking-at "\\s)")
          (save-excursion (forward-char 1) (funcall orig-fun)))))

(add-function :around show-paren-data-function #'my-show-paren-any)
```

Comment: Have you defined a custom function called #'add-function? On startup, emacs gives this warning\n "Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/naman/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: add-function"

Comment: @namandixit `add-function` is new in emacs 24.4. See http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/12/29/whats-new-in-emacs-24-4/.

Comment: @Tobias Is there any alternative for 24.3?

Comment: @namandixit The alternative to `add-function` would be `defadvice`. But, that does also not help since `show-paren-data-function` is also new in emacs24.4.

Comment: @Tobias: Indeed, the lack of show-paren-data-function is the problem.  As for `add-function` it can't be replaced by `defadvice` (you were probably thinking of `advice-add`).

Comment: @namandixit: There's no probably some way to get it to work under 24.3, but it'd be more work.  You might prefer to try the latest Emacs pretest (24.3.93), which is *very* close to what Emacs-24.4 will be when released.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Emacs 25.xx (compiled from git today). It says `show-paren-data-function` is void.

Comment: You need to `(require 'paren)` beforehand, since that's where `show-paren-data-function ` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

What's important to remember here is that Emacs's point is *between* two characters, not *on* a character. For the `show-paren` facility to trigger, the point must be immediately outside a paren, whether opening or closing. The observed dissymmetry is caused by the block cursor being placed, arbitrarily, on the character after (rather than before) the point.

If this disturbs you, then a workaround would be to use a line cursor rather than a block cursor.

`show-paren-mode` is being enhanced for the next but one release, such that it will trigger also with the point immediately inside a paren.

Comment: Which version is "next but one"? I have 24.5, and parentheses are still not highlighted when cursor is at the closing one (block cursor can't be between symbols, only at one of them).

Answer (score 0):

The following advice does what you want. When the block cursor is "on" the opening parenthesis, the closing parenthesis is highlighted. When the block cursor is "on" the closing parenthesis, the opening parenthesis is highlighted.

```el
(advice-add show-paren-data-function
            :around
            (lambda (orig-fun)
              (cond ((looking-at "\\s(")
                     (funcall orig-fun))
                    ((looking-at "\\s)")
                     (save-excursion (forward-char 1) (funcall orig-fun))))))
```

Refer to my answer on the Emacs Stack Exchange site: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63458/17507. In that answer, I provide a full explanation of the code above, and also a suggested variant.