# Remove trailing highlight [EMACS config]

Tags: emacs, highlight

I have been looking into adding some extra functionality on my emacs config file.

What I'm trying to have is Highlighting matching parens,
however using `mic-paren` the default behaviour selects closing parens only after the cursor (this works fine for opening paren).

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648067/emacs-matching-parenthesis-when-cursor-is-on-closing-parenthesis) answer the desired functionality is almost achieved, however the afterglow is distracting.

```
;;; Will highlight when cursor on closing parenthesis, however leaves afterglow...
(defadvice mic-paren-highlight (around cursorOnClosing activate)
  "Dirty hack to highlight sexps with closing delim below cursor"
  (if (eq (char-syntax (following-char)) ?\) )
      (let ((paren-priority 'close))
        (save-excursion
          (forward-char)
          ad-do-it))
    ad-do-it))
```

Any better alternatives, or some correction you could give me to get the desired behaviour? thanks in advance

Comment: Does `(show-paren-mode 1)` not do what you want?

Comment: just checked `(show-paren-mode 1)` shows matching parens only when the cursor is after the closing paren, I'm trying to get it to work when the cursor is on top.

Comment: OK, I thought that was what you were saying, but I wasn't sure. May I ask why you want it this way? I think the reason it is this way is that you type a closing paren, and then you see the opening paren it matches. Otherwise (unless your parens are autocompleted - which they probably are), you will have to type a closing paren, and then move the cursor backwards to see the marching opening paren.

Comment: Both for aesthetic reasons and to work in conjunction with vim-like '%' jumping through parens, also since I'm trying to learn more about emacs and going down the rabbit hole. I do see your point for the intended reason for that functionality though which I didn't think of +1

Comment: well welcome to the rabbit hole. You might see me on your way down. Also, check out emacs.stackexchange.com. This kind of question will get answered there much quicker, and it is a *really* great, supportive community.

Comment: I don't understand what the question title has to do with the question. Is this about highlighting parentheses or highlighting trailing whitespace, or something else? And you don't seem to actually describe (specify) what behavior you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that does come across this, the new release of [emacs 25.1 Released September 17, 2016](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.25.1)

From the [News](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.25.1) File:

```
In Show Paren Mode, a parenthesis can be highlighted when point
stands inside it, and certain parens can be highlighted when point is
at BOL or EOL, or in whitespace there.  To enable these, customize,
respectively, 'show-paren-when-point-inside-paren' or
'show-paren-when-point-in-periphery'.
```

So in order to fix this problem:

```
'show-paren-when-point-inside-paren'
```